# How to do HtmlPage refresh using HTMLUNIT Java?

Tags: java, refresh, htmlunit

I am facing an issue while refreshing the page.
I am using HTMLUNIT.I am using WebClient and HTMLPAge to access a resource.

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HtmlPage


WebClient webClient = new WebClient()
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage(resource)
```

I need to refresh the page in order to get the new data from the resource.
I tried to clear the cache webClient.getCache().clear();
and also tried to access the resource again with

```
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage(resource)`.
```

I am getting the same previous data from the resource.
I am beginner, can anyone please guide me how to do that.

Thanks,
Naga

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this simple one?

```
page.refresh();
```

Should do the work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem some months ago and I did solve it by clearing the cache. Make sure you're using the appropriate variables. Give this code a try (correct any syntactical errors):

```
public static HtmlPage myGetPage(WebClient webClient, String url,
  boolean clearCache) throws Exception {
    if (clearCache) {
        webClient.getCache().clear();
    }
    return webClient.getPage(url);
}

public void myMethod() {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/268273";
    HtmlPage page = myGetPage(webClient, url, false); // We don't clear de cache
    System.out.println(page.asXml()); // Should return original value
    page = myGetPage(webClient, url, true); // We clear the cache
    System.out.println(page.asXml()); // Should return the new value
}
```

PS: Of course, use your URL :)

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache, it did not work for me :( . is there any way that i can achieve this?